# How to create a dummy columns in SSIS 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl, attunity

I have a Flat file (.csv)

```
ID, Name
1, ABC
2, CDE
3, DEF
```

I want to the Insert these columns into the target Oracle Table with the sysdate to be inserted into the Load_Dt Column

```
Create Table Temp1
(Load_Dt Date,
ID Number,
Name Varchar2(10));
```

**Environment:**

- SSIS 2008 R2
- Oracle 10g
- Attunity V 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `DataFlow Task` add a `Derived Column Transformation`

Add a new column of type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` with the expression:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)GETDATE()
```

Read more about `Derived Column Transformation` in this [Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation)

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.  Since my Target is Oracle i have to use GETDATE() only and the data type is Database Timestamp (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)

Comment: Happy to help. I edited the data type and upvoted ur question :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with the Derived Column Transformation.